# How to replace a component in a MaterialUI component?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

MaterialUI has styling functionality but it's also possible to customize a component by replacing a subcomponent.

For example, the MaterialUI documentation on [`<Slider>`](https://mui.com/components/slider/) links to a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/s0f87?file=/demo.tsx) where the `<Thumb>`-component is swapped out.

But it's not really clear to me what's happening here, and I can't find any documentation, examples or tutorials on how to do that for other components.

How should I proceed when for example I want to replace the `<Track>` component? To be clear, I know how to swap out a component (that's clear form the `<Thumb>` component but I feel like I'm missing documentation on what to replace it by.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slider has a `components` prop. Specifically:

```js
components?: {
  Root?: React.ElementType;
  Track?: React.ElementType;
  Rail?: React.ElementType;
  Thumb?: React.ElementType;
  Mark?: React.ElementType;
  MarkLabel?: React.ElementType;
  ValueLabel?: React.ElementType;
};
```

The Airbnb component in the example has `components={{ Thumb: AirbnbThumbComponent }}`. If you want to replace the Track instead, all you need to do is:

```js
function MyCustomTrackComponent() {
  /* ... */
}

<Slider components={{ Track: MyCustomTrackComponent }} />
```

Comment: I got this far already but it's not clear at all what exactly to replace components by. What props do we need to accept and what should we do with them? What data do we have access to? I'm expecting API documentation for substitute components.

Comment: @Plumpie Unfortunately, the MUI docs only document the API of "usable" components, not the "clockwork" of other components. If you want to customise one of those, you need to check the [implementation page](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/mui-material/src/Slider/Slider.js) on their repo. Line 139 is the Track. It's just a span element styled with their emotion API.